# How to fix 'undefined' error with $scope.detailsForm

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularjs and have written a small program but facing the error "scope.detailsForm" as undefined. Could someone help me what is the issue with the below code.

b.js file:

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', []);
app.controller("my-cont", function($scope) {
    $scope.detailsForm.clickme.$setValidity("error1",true);
});
```

b.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="b.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="my-app" ng-controller="my-cont">
<form method="get" name="detailsForm" ng-model="detailsForm">
  <button  name='clickme'    ng-disabled="detailsForm.clickme.$error.error1">Click Me!</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want disable button?

Comment: I want to know issue with above code

Comment: form1 undefined. I don't see form1 in file b.html

Comment: Maybe it's not related but you have </html> tag before body

Comment: Sorry now I edited question to remove form1 but still getting the error "$scope.detailsForm is undefined"

Comment: You're binding detailsForm to a <form> which is not correct (look here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)

Comment: An easy way to debug is to print out $scope in console and see what values are available. I suspect that detailsForm may be added to scope after initialization of the controller. If that is the case you should set up a $scope.$watch to wait for detailsForm to be available

Comment: @Dario didn't look up the documentation but think it looks correct for form validation, it is not the same as when you wish to bind a model.

Comment: @cYrixmorten, Thank you, It is working after I use $scope.$watch, is it possible to add detailsForm to $scope before initialization of the controller

Comment: No problem :) don't think that it is, however if you do `$scope.$applyAsync()` just after `$scope.detailsForm.clickme.$setValidity("error1",true);`, it should disable the button in what seems to be instant.

Comment: But, what is your goal exactly? if you simply want to be able to control disable/enable of the button, I must agree with Dario, that it is easier binding directly to a model in the controller. e.g. `<button  name='clickme'    ng-disabled="disableButton">Click Me!</button>` , and then `$scope.disableButton = true` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you can not get it when the controller is not built, you need to wait for the html to be processed by Angular. Here's an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/a9EjwqlOEix2KtYWqenD?p=preview).

As you'll see in the console, the first log will echo undefined, and the second will echo the form.

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.controller("MyCont", ['$scope', function($scope) {

   console.log($scope.detailsForm);
   $scope.onClicked = function()
   {
      console.log($scope.detailsForm);
   }
}]);
```